# Php array move element to other postion with key value pair

Tags: php

I want to move array element with key to other position of array.

My actual Array

```
  Array
    (
        [24] => Birthday
        [25] => Christmas
        [26] => Congratulations
        [27] => Halloween
        [28] => Mothers Day
    )
```

I want to move `[25] => Christmas` element like below.

```
Array
    (
        [24] => Birthday  
        [26] => Congratulations
        [27] => Halloween
        [25] => Christmas
        [28] => Mothers Day         
    )
```

Comment: `$newArray = [24 => $oldArray[24],26 => $oldArray[26],27 => $oldArray[27],25 => $oldArray[25],28 => $oldArray[28]];`

Comment: actually key is db table id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live on ide1: http://ideone.com/yJ1e3N

Use `uasort` to keep key-value association while ordering with a custom logic using a closure:

```
$order = [
   'Birthday' => 1,
   'Congratulations' => 2,
   'Halloween' => 3,
   'Christmas' => 4,
   'Mothers Day' => 5 
];

uasort($array, function($a,$b) use ($order){
  return $order[$a] > $order[$b];
});
```

With this script you can use any custom order logic you need by assigning the right value to the array `$order`.
This will be also very fast if you have many elements as the right order is accessed using the `key`s of the `$order` array (and not by a linear scan).

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the data from table, you can add another column as order_column and specify the order in that column. Then modify your select query such that you ORDER BY order_column.